# How to execute shell commands with k8s module on a Pod through Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am having some trouble trying to execute shell commands with [k8s](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/kubernetes) module. As far as I am aware, k8s only possess `k8s_exec` to pass commands. Although, this module is similar to Ansible [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html) module, which does not have a very important functionality that I desperately need: manage and use environment variables on a pod.
A workaround that I have currently found is using `kubectl exec` function to execute shell commands on the remote machines. I am aware this is not the best approach.

Here is a playbook that illustrates some examples for the problem:

```
---
- hosts: localhost #group of hosts on host file
  connection: local
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: '{{ ansible_playbook_python }}'
  collections:
    - community.kubernetes

    - name: Define Retail Home Path with k8s_exec module (not working!!!)
      k8s_exec:
        kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig_path | mandatory }}"
        namespace: redmine
        pod: redminetisl-gitlab-54d7759df8-l52cb #pod name
        command: export RETAIL_HOME=/u01/app/rms
    - name: Define Retail Home Path with kubectl exec module (working!!!)
      command: kubectl --namespace=redmine exec redminetisl-gitlab-54d7759df8-l52cb -- /bin/bash -c "export RETAIL_HOME=/u01/app/rms"
```

Is there any way to execute shell commands and use/manage environment variables on a remote machine with k8s module?

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansible/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use this mechanism to change process environment variables.  This is generally true in Unix: one process can't change another's environment variables, except that the parent can specify them at the moment it creates the child (and even then technically it's the child process running the parent's code that sets them).  You can see the same thing using for example `ssh`:

```sh
ssh somewhere export RETAIL_HOME=/u01/app/rms
ssh somewhere echo \$RETAIL_HOME
```

If you want to set an environment variable and you need it to affect the pod's main process, you need to edit the Deployment spec; when you change this Kubernetes will redeploy the Pod(s) to have the new variables.  For something like a filesystem path also consider just baking it into your image's `Dockerfile`.

Since it is very routine for Pods to get deleted (a Deployment update will cause all of its Pods to get deleted and recreated; the cluster can do it on its own if a node needs to get shut down) trying to use `kubectl exec` to make changes directly inside a pod isn't especially reliable.  I wouldn't try to "manage" a pod with Ansible at all.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that manipulating the environment variables of a pod is unreliable with Ansible?

Comment: Manipulating the environment variables of a pod is _impossible_.  You can't change the environment of the running process, and you can't change the environment part of the pod spec once it's been deployed.

Comment: So this whole concept of manipulating environment variables needs to be rethinked right? Environment variables can be only accessed, never created or manipulated I right? I am currently using Rancher to create and manage my kubernetes containers. As such, all the pods are being created through a Docker image. The only way I have is to define those env variables at the time of the deployment?